Flow Table HTML to Email Template
We're working on an email template that we created via Flow. We have a Rich Text Area field called Invoice Lines Rich Text created on the custom Invoice object that is being used to dynamically fill out the table shown below - this field is pulling the values from the flow variable called EmailTemplateHTMLVariable. The issue we're facing is that the flow renders the table differently when we use the merge field in the Lightning Email Template - there's gaps in between the cells. I have added as much Inline CSS however, when I inspected the element the border-collapse: collapse was overridden and showed as border-collapse: separate. Is there any way we can add/update/use to remove the gaps in between the cells? Or are there any suggestions you can provide?
Here's the html code we added in the Flow Text Template

  
    Period/Période
    Owed / Payable
    Payments/Paiements
    Balance
  
  {!EmailTemplateHTMLVariable}
  
    Please pay this amount./S.V.P. veuillez payer ce montant.
    {!FinalBalanceOwedVariable}
  


